# CTRL+F3 is searching complete solution in VS2008, not the current document

Tags: visual-studio, search

I recently noticed that when I select a word and press CTRL+F3 in VS2008, it searches for that word in the whole solution, and the following appears at the status bar: Find "XXXX", Match case, Entire solution.

When I do the same thing in VS2010, I get to search only in the current document, not the complete solution. I want the same behavior in VS2008, and in fact, I thought, that is the default behavior in VS2008 as well. May be I did something ... anyone knows how can I get back the behavior of searching only in the current document using CTRL+F3 in VS2008?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ctrl+F3` uses the last-used settings from the search dialog. If you open that up (using `Ctrl+F`) and change the "Look in" option to "Current Document", it will then search just within the current document next time you do `Ctrl+F3`.

Comment: Wow !! That was fast - great. Thanks.